# send form after form with curl php

Tags: php, forms, curl

I have a question for you.
I have this code:

```
        $postData2 = array(  
        'From'=>'20/10/2016',
        'To' =>'30/10/2016'
      );  

      $postData = array(  
        'User' =>'Sebastian',
        'Password' =>'12345'
      );  

//1.- login...
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://web.com/login.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; es-CL; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    curl_exec ($ch);

    //2.- send dates...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://web.com/askdates.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec ($ch);

    //3.- answer...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://web.com/answer.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; es-CL; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    $page=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $page;
```

The first step is ok.. the login is right.
I think the second step is ok, but the answer for this second form is shown in https://web.com/answer.php so i wrote the 3 step... But i only see https://web.com/answer.php without post information.

What do i have to do to correct this?

PS: Firstly, i wrote the two first steps but the answer was negative.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question exactly but if your trying to send multiple curl requests at the same time this is how:

```
<?php
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://lxr.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);

?>
```

So basically create each individual request but don't execute them yet then use curl_multi_init() to join the requests together into one, after that execute it.

If you want more detail on how have a read on here: http://php.net/curl_multi_init

Comment: I tried this but I think I dont have to join the requests together into one because I need to login first and then I can look for a movie in the specific dates. Thanks for your reply! somebody know how to login first and then searches for a movie and get that information??

Comment: create 2 functions() one for login $login =  curl_init() ; and one for grabbing $grabing = curl_init()

Comment: A bit like EaBangalore said create 2 functions one for logging in and one for grabbing then get the response from the logging in function to see if it passes the tests if so carry on with the grabbing function, im not a pro PHP guy but thats how I would do it.